# Getting error in SolrNet

Tags: c#, solrnet

Getting error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

```
public void IndexPlayers()
{
    new SolrBaseRepository.Instance<Player>().Start();

    var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Player>>();
    var players = new PlayerRepository().GetPlayers();

    solr.Add(players);
    solr.Commit();
}
```

while add players in Solr .

Comment: Get the rest of the error message. If necessary, go to the Solr logs.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I am getting this in my log file.

INFO  - 2015-06-19 22:16:26.222; [   ] org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall; [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/info/logging params={wt=json&since=1434741154441&_=1434752186219} status=0 
Can you please help me to understand what is this...???

Comment: that's only an unrelated call to the logging endpoint. You need to find the error you got.